# Installing Node and NPM in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, fedora

I've having troubles with npm in my Linux Fedora 27. After installing and reinstalling doing so many complex files movements, finally I made ir work. But for every npm update I have a new headache because always some file or directory haven't permission for write or something like that.

Since last node and npm update (8.10.0 and 5.7.1 respectivelly) I figured out that installing them as superuser ( `$ su` ) everything go right, but only under superuser level.

What can I do to use npm and node without problems as a common user?

Maybe it isn't nacessary change anything. I don't know what kind of problems can give me using my linux always as a superuser

I'm a relativelly new Linux User, so apologies by my noob concepts and supositions

Comment: Did you try this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora ?

Comment: Yes @Csaba, but it doesn't work in Fedora 27. I just found a solution. I'm posting it here

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution for my problem, but I think that besides is the best way for installing nodejs in Linux or Unix derivates:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm